# WebView with a transparent background

Tags: xamarin, webview

How to create WebView with a transparent background in Xamarin.Forms PCL?

Thic code in Xaml is not working.

```
<WebView Source="http://xxx.pl/" BackgroundColor="Transparent"/>
```

Comment: does the page that you're loading also have a transparent background?

Comment: It is set -> bgcolor="transparent"

Answer (score 1):

In addition to setting the background color/transparency/alpha in the HTML, You have to set the native control's background color:

- Android: set the `WebView` background color to `Black`

  `BackgroundColor = 0;`
- iOS: set the `WKWebView` or `UIWebView` background to `Clear`

  `BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear`